# How can I delete an element of a List<string> related to another List<string>?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have two lists of strings:

```
List<string> a;
List<string> b;
```

With `a.RemoveAll()` I remove empty elements or specific values in list a.

Now I want to remove elements at the same index in list b related to the indexes that were removed with `a.RemoveAll()`

How can I accomplish that?

I already have coded a workaround with `for ()... loops` but the code looks more than awkward. There should be a better solution

Comment: Can you provide sample input and expected output? Also, your for loop would be helpful to see and we can help you with it.

Comment: The fact that you have two lists that are being edited "in parallel" like this maybe indicates that you have a bad abstraction in your code; can you describe what the lists are and why there are two of them?  A better solution might be to have one list containing pairs of strings, instead of a pair of lists of strings.

Comment: Stick with the `for` loop. The elements aren't "related" if they are in two separate lists. Make one list with an object containing both if they really are "related", or make a single list of tuples, ...

Comment: @IanMercer: I beat you by just a couple seconds. :-) Great minds think alike?

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to rephrase your question. You want to remove the elements at certain indices of `b`. Which indices exactly? Those indices of `a` that would have been removed if `a.RemoveAll(somePredicate)` were called. Did I understand correctly?

You can use LINQ:

```
a.Select((x, y) => (element: x, index: y))
    .Where(x => somePredicate(x.element) && x.index < b.Count)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.index)
    .ToList().ForEach(x => b.RemoveAt(x.index));
```

If you don't mind creating a new list, it can be shorter:

```
var newList = b.Select((x, y) => (element: x, index: y))
    .Where(x => somePredicate(a[x.index])).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with LINQ... time to change that obviously.

Answer (score -1):

```
  var myList = new List<string> { "A", "x", "x", "B" };
```

if you want to find indexes of "x"

```
   var indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, myList.Count).Where(x => myList[x] == "x").ToList();
```